# \textsf or \sffamily have different font than \section{}

Tags: fonts, bold, sans-serif, computer-modern

This code

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\textsf{Test}

{\sffamily Test}

Normal Font
\end{document}
```

renders as this picture below. Why the text in `sffamily` is formatted unexpected with different font than text in `section`?

[image: Different fonts]

Comment: the section heading is in a bold font, do you find that unexpected?

Comment: Oh, I almost forget it. But do they have the same font family, but not the same font shape?

Comment: You need to distinguish between font *shape* (e.g., serif and sans-serif), *weight* (e.g., medium and bold), and *size*. When using the `scrartcl` document class, sectioning headers are typeset in `\bfseries`, `\Large`, and `\sffamily` by default.

Comment: I test with `{\sffamily\bfseries Test}` and get the same rendering as `\section`, but why have they different form without `\bfseries`? (See the "t", for example)

Comment: it is not clear what difference you see, but bold fonts are not just distorted versions they are drawn by the font designer who can make any variation they wish.

Comment: For example, the charater `t` is rendered with rounded corner by bold, and with sharp corner without bold. Is it normal that a font family has different "face" for each series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the standard sans serif, but as is common for headings, large and bold:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\textbf{\textsf{\Large Test}}  \textsf{\Large Test}



Normal Font
\end{document}
```

The metafont sources have

cmss10.mf

```
crisp#:=0pt#;      % diameter of serif corners
tiny#:=0pt#;      % diameter of rounded corners
fine#:=0pt#;      % diameter of sharply rounded corners
...
flare#:=25/36pt#;    % diameter of bulbs or breadth of terminals
```

cmsbx10.mf

```
crisp#:=26/36pt#;    % diameter of serif corners
tiny#:=26/36pt#;    % diameter of rounded corners
fine#:=9/36pt#;      % diameter of sharply rounded corners
...
flare#:=40/36pt#;    % diameter of bulbs or breadth of terminals
```

So the bold is more rounded by design

Comment: Do Sans-serif have rounded corner with Bold-Series and sharp corner without Bold-Series?

Comment: @lazyboy yes, for computer modern sans, I added an image with bigger zoom

Comment: @lazyboy I'll add the font source

Comment: It's really gut to known. I don't know it before, and all my texts are (typography) very boring. LoL <- self humor